# How to load a part of Image on Demand like GMap Does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, web, stream

I have a big big image lets say 1000 MP (700MB), Like a Map of a particular area,  What I want to do is load only the specific part if if zoom in to the image.
This is important to make the app efficient to work in web.

I did it by storing the image by slicing it in various part and on demand load only that sliced image available.

The slices are done according to the zoom level.

But I don't want to do this way, Is there any efficient and proper way to do it, how any map does it ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure what you did is how google maps does it.

Comment: Yes, it is normal practice at any digital map)More efficient way is to use SVG, but SVG is vector graphics, not a raster

Answer (score 0):

Some services, articles and frameworks:

- https://www.maptiler.com/
- http://blog.davidelner.com/create-map-with-tilemill-and-leaflet/
- http://polymaps.org/docs/

If you google "slippy map nodejs", you will find a lot of ready to use tile servers

Answer (score 0):

Try [**layload-image**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazyload-image):

HTMLImageElement extension for lazy loading. Images will be loaded when they are shown.

Install lazyload-image via npm or bower.

```
# via npm 
$ npm install lazyload-image

# via bower 
$ bower install lazyload-image
```

**Usage**

```
Load lazyload-image.html in your HTML.

<link rel="import" href="lazyload-image.html">
Modify your <img> elements such as following.

<img is="lazyload-image" src="path/to/your/image.jpg" offset="200" width="100" height="100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you don't want the logic to be backend driven / lazy loading, I could recommend an approach using **Object Streams**.

The approach:

1. Take your large image and break into smaller ones [ As you're already doing ]
2. Pack them in an array so that the default zoom images go in first and then for each zoom level +/-. Lets say a frame of 10 images make up a view. Then you pack the images in such fashion:

   - Frame of 10 at Zoom 0
   - Frame of 10 at Zoom +10
   - Frame of 10 at Zoom -10
   - Frame of 10 at Zoom +20
   - Frame of 10 at Zoom -20
3. Use an object streaming library such as [Stream-JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) , to start emitting the images from the server to the client.
4. On the client, receive the frames and save them in memory to be shown when user pans/zooms.

The Key difference is that the data is not truly lazy-loaded as it is not relying on the user zooming in/out to get the required images. The frames are rather loaded in memory to give the user minimum wait time i.e. Optimized for time, not memory.

All the best. Hope this helps. Let me know if a more detailed implementation is needed.